# Importing an app engine java endpoint module in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

So, I want to import an app engine java endpoint module to one of my android studio projects. What I did was `File>Import Module>` Then i specified the app engine directory that i previously created. 

It imported all the classes and required files. Then i configured the run configuration and added an `Appengine DevApp server` and configured. I ran the backend module and all ran perfectly and showed me the welcome page in an web browser.

I also added the backed in my `settings.gradle` 
what it is now is `include ':app', ':backend'`

But when i try to import any class to my app portion from my backend,

 for example
if i write `import com.example.backend.myApi.MyApi` it shows that the specified class does not exist.

Now how to import an endpoint module to my android app?  Another thing i noticed that when I create a new `Google Cloud Module` i can specify the `Client Module`. Can I specify the `Client Module` manually?

Comment: In `settings.gradle` you should have `include ':app', ':backend'`

Comment: please read what i have posted. I did that too. @tomrozb

Comment: You have `'backend'` not `':backend'`. This way it should work.

Comment: sorry, typo while posting. I have it.

Comment: So try `gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs` then reopen/re-import the project.

Comment: @tomrozb how to import the module? Is there any way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68085/discussion-between-s-kar-and-tomrozb).

Answer (score 0):

"What I did was File>Import Module> Then i specified the app engine directory that i previously created. It imported all the classes and required files."

That's wierd.  I'm using AS 1.2 and it still doesn't (appear to me) to support importing Eclipse GPE app engine projects.   You have to create a new module and then move/copy the sources over.